# "Became" vs "become"

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-tense, present-tense, simple-past

I'm not sure about the verb tense I should use here:

> Run this definition so that the previous changes **become/became** visible.

I think the correct one is Present Simple but it sounds better with Past Simple.

Comment: General Reference. OP's text is clearly *a sentence*, since it starts with a capital letter and ends with a full stop. It's irrelevant that we could grammatically include that string of words within a longer sentence such as *"Did you run this definition so that the previous changes **became** visible?"*, where past tense is valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Run this definition so that the previous changes become visible.

You'd use become, the sentence is in the present tense. Became is the PAST tense.

Comment: Right. **All** imperatives are in the present tense, by definition.

Comment: @JohnLawler passing on this correction from  user F.E.:  "Imperatives are headed by the base form (i.e. plain form) of a verb -- not by a present tense form of a verb. This can be seen when the verb BE is used. That is, the imperative is NOT in present-tense." as commented here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196806/if-we-become-friends-or-became-or-were-to-become?noredirect=1#comment414906_196806

Answer (score 0):

become is used in the following context

`Run this definition so that the previous changes become visible`

and became is used like this :-

`Ran this definition so that the previous changes became visible`

Comment: The latter does not make sense to me.