# "... if we become friends" or "became" or "were to become"?

Tags: conditionals

"I would feel happy if we become friends." (become)

or

"I would feel happy if we became friends."  (became)

or

"I would feel happy if we were to become friends." (were to become)

**Update:** or

"I would feel happy if we could become friends." (could become)

Perhaps related, I noticed a comment on another answer saying that imperatives are always in present tense.  Is "become" an imperative in the examples above?

Comment: *"I noticed a comment on another answer saying that imperatives are always in present tense."* <== Huh? Could you provide a link to that?

Comment: @F.E. I meant just the "we become friends" part, which I probably incorrectly thought of as an imperative. The more I think, the more it doesn't make sense as an imperative but I am still not sure. The comment was related to a correct usage of the imperative, and for your reference it is the comment on this answer: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/72612/23576

Comment: In *Run this definition so that the previous changes become visible*, the imperative word is *Run*. (The imperative is always in the present tense refers to *become* as opposed to *became*. If *become* here were the imperative, the command would be *Become visible!* The imperative verb is preceeded by the assumed subject *you* (singular or plural).

Comment: Imperatives are headed by the *base* form (i.e. *plain* form) of a verb -- not by a *present tense* form of a verb. This can be seen when the verb *BE* is used. That is, the imperative is NOT in present-tense.

Comment: @medica Yes, one can. That's the plain form (or the base form), which is identical with the lexical base of the verb. The plain form is used in the following constructions: infinitival, subjunctive, imperative. Consider: _"Somebody at the front **write** their name on the board"_ -- which is an imperative with a 3rd person subject. Imperatives use only the plain form (never a present-tense form).

Comment: !!! Honestly, I have never thought of a 3rd person imperative, and have tried to imagine it on occasion. Very interesting, and explains well why it has to be the plain form. So, someone was not quite correct in saying *become* in the example "Run..." is present tense. Or I misunderstood. In any case, again, I never fail to learn something about language when you're around. Thanks!

Comment: @medica You might find this post interesting. :) http://english.stackexchange.com/a/137100/57102

Comment: @F.E., medica, semantax. I think it's easiest to see, as you said F.E., with imperatives that use *BE*. For example, we don't say *Are quiet!* or *Are* sensible!*, but *Be quiet* and *Be sensible*. There's not really any meaningful way here to say that *BE* agrees with *you* or anything like that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are suggesting a conditional (hypothetical) type of pairing. The usual example starts with the *if* phrase:

> If we were to become friends, I would be very happy.

Reversed, it still holds it's form.

> I would be very happy if we were to become friends.

The other sentences are certainly understandable, and basically mean the same thing. But there are some guidelines.

> - I *will* be happy if we *become* friends.
> - I would be happy if we became friends.

I don't know anything about the *need* for imperatives. The imperative might look like this:

BE happy if we become friends! (strange command)
Eat your dinner if you want to grow up! (common command)

Comment: +1 thank you. Re the imperative I (perhaps incorrectly) meant the "we become friends" part as the imperative and thus "become" in present tense. But that probably doesn't make sense so please ignore it.