# No one + plural verb

Tags: grammaticality

The sentence is:

No one forget about the issue, please.

From what I've read on the internet, 'no one' always takes a singular verb, but somehow 'no one forgets' doesn't sound right to me. But I don't know why it doesn't sound right. Probably because this is an imperative sentence? No? Can someone please explain?

Comment: The imperative takes a bare verb: No body move! The declarative: This dog is vicious. *No one forgets* that without risking being bitten. See the comment thread [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196806/if-we-become-friends-or-became-or-were-to-become#comment414935_196806).

Comment: So the title is incorrect. The fact that 'forget' is first person plural in 'We forget so quickly' doesn't make it first person plural in 'I forget my keys at least once a week', 'Do you forget your keys so frequently?', 'Forget about it!' or 'No one forget about this, please.'

Comment: Oh, English. I cry.

Comment: @blergh - I don't blame you a bit. I've been speaking this language for decades, and I'm still learning new things. ')

Answer (score -2):

If English had a third person imperative, I would say it was that, but otherwise I would go with a subjunctive expressing a wish or desire or command, kinda like a jussive subjunctive in Latin.

Other subjunctives like this in English: *God bless America*, *God save the King*. I'm sure there are some good examples without God too, but subjunctives are pretty dusty in English now...

Comment: Said someone wiser than I am: "Consider: *Somebody at the front write **their** name on the board*" -- an imperative with **a 3rd person subject**. This is an imperative, something different than the subjunctive.

Comment: My first thought was the same, but looking around the internet, I don't see any agreement that a 3rd person imperative exists in English (can you?). You could just as easily say "_Somebody at the front write **your** name on the board_". Maybe it's safer to say it's a jussive? Check out [this article by Nordquist](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/Jussive.htm).

Comment: If you accept Nordquist's proposal that all are subsets of Jussives (to which I have no objection, nor the expertise to object), then your point is well taken.

Comment: In English, 'jussive' can only describe a category, its not a unique mood, and of course imperatives fall into this category. However, the first examples in his article are of *non-imperative jussives* which are subjunctives, including "_Everybody listen_" which is the same form as the OP's sentence. The only thing that comes close to a 3rd person imperative in English is a periphrastic construction using _let_

Comment: That is better debated with a grammarian or linguist than with me. My example came from one such person. :)

Comment: That's great, but can you point to any evidence to support your grammarian/linguist's opinion? For example, if you look up English verb tables ([example 1](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/be.html), [example 2](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-forget.html)), you will find only forms for you and we (let's...); the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood#English) on the imperative mood makes no mention of a 3rd person. I only really have any strong experience with Latin and Spanish otherwise, which both also use subjunctives in this way.